# $addToSet $each exception in casbah 2.6.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, casbah, mongodb-scala

After moving from casbah 2.6.1 to 2.6.2, I got the following exception for $addToSet $each update queries.

```
val s = Set(1,2,3)
$addToSet("ids") $each(s)
```

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.mongodb.casbah.query.dsl.AddToSetOp$$anon$1.$each(scala.collection.Seq,
>   com.mongodb.casbah.query.AsQueryParam)

Does anyone know what could have changed here?

Comment: What version of scala?  How did you upgrade?  Works fine locally and when copying the getting started part of: http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/tutorial.html#getting-started, I couldn't reproduce

Comment: Just tested against scala 2.9.2 and casbah 2.6.2 and it also works as expected - could you clear your dependencies / local cache and try again?